# Can I get a string length in physical units (cm, pixels, dots) as printed by latex from python?

Tags: python, printing, latex

I am using python to automatically create a huge table that I then want to pass to LaTeX. I would like to know a length of certain strings as they will be printed by LaTeX. Something like:

```
get_latex_length(string,font,fontsize)
```

Does such a thing exists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to get string size using `font.getsize()` from Python Imaging Library. If the same font is used in LaTeX this could help:

```
from PIL import ImageFont

def get_latex_length(string, font, fontsize):
    font = ImageFont.truetype(font, fontsize)        
    return font.getsize(string)

print(get_latex_length('Some text', 'Arial.ttf', 12))
```

The output is width and height of the given text string in pixels: `(54, 10)`

Comment: Thanks. You are missing something like size = `font.getsize(string)` and `return size` I actually use `latin modern` fonts. One can download them from here: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/lm/fonts/opentype/public/lm and then just use `print(get_latex_length('Some text', '/path/to/lmroman8-regular.otf', 8))` or corresponding file and font size. This is useful to know what size LaTeX is internally using: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24599/what-point-pt-font-size-are-large-etc